# rlike in scala dataframe is giving the error

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, rlike

I am trying to convert the below Hive SQL statement into Spark dataframe but getting an error.

```
case when (lower(message_txt) rlike '.*sampletext(\\s?is\\s?)newtext.*' ) then 'P' else 'Y'
```

Sample data: `message_txt = "This is new sampletext, followed by newtext"`

Please help me to provide equivalent spark dataframe statement.

Comment: what are you trying to extract from the message ?

Answer (score 0):

Add **`end`** at the end of `case statement` in sql.

---

**`Example:`**

**`In spark Sql:`**

```
val df=Seq(("This is new sampletext, followed by newtext")).toDF("message_txt")
df.createOrReplaceTempView("tmp")
spark.sql("select case when (lower(message_txt) rlike '.sampletext(\\s?is\\s?)newtext.' ) then 'P' else 'Y' end from tmp").show()

//Result
//+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
//|CASE WHEN lower(message_txt) RLIKE .sampletext(s?iss?)newtext. THEN P ELSE Y END|
//+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
//|                                                                               Y|
//+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

**`In dataframe API:`**

```
df.withColumn("status", when(lower(col("message_txt")).rlike(".sampletext(\\s?is\\s?)newtext."),"P").otherwise("Y")).show()

//Result
//+--------------------+------+
//|         message_txt|status|
//+--------------------+------+
//|This is new sampl...|     Y|
//+--------------------+------+
```

---

**`UPDATE:`**

Checking for strings sampletext and newtext in message_txt column.

```
//using rlike
df.withColumn("status", when(lower(col("message_txt")).rlike("sampletext.*newtext"),"P").otherwise("Y")).show()

//using like
df.withColumn("status", when(lower(col("message_txt")).like("%sampletext%newtext%"),"P").otherwise("Y")).show()

//+--------------------+------+
//|         message_txt|status|
//+--------------------+------+
//|This is new sampl...|     P|
//+--------------------+------+
```

Comment: The message _txt  is having sampletext and newtext so it should display 'P' as status correct?

Comment: Are you sure this `regular expression` working in Hive and producing 'P' for the above text?

Comment: Kind of regular expression. If the message_txt is having those strings then I am setting 'P'

Comment: @CNR, You can use `.rlike` or `.like` functions for this case check my updated answer as i have added both functions working examples.

Answer (score 0):

Use `when(lower($"value").rlike(""".sampletext(\sis\s?)newtext."""),lit('P')).otherwise("Y")`

```
scala> df.withColumn("condition",when(lower($"value").rlike(""".sampletext(\s?is\s?)newtext."""),lit('P')).otherwise("Y")).show(false)
+-------------------------------------------+---------+
|value                                      |condition|
+-------------------------------------------+---------+
|This is new sampletext, followed by newtext|Y        |
+-------------------------------------------+---------+
```